# Sequelize - How do I "select" instances of a model if a relation exists to another model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using PostgreSQL in a Node.JS app and I'm using SequelizeJS as an ORM. I have the following query:

Let's say I have two models:

- `User(name,email)`
- `Category(name,createdBy)`

`Category.createdBy` is a foreign key referencing `User.id`
These two tables have a many-to-many relationship:

```
Category.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'UserCategory'});
User.belongsToMany(models.Category, {through: 'UserCategory'});
```

If a category is associated to a user, a mapping will exist on the UserCategory table. Else it won't.

How to "select" instances which will find me all categories which are either createdBy a user X or associated to user X, i.e. `(categories associated to user X) + (categories created by user X)`?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Sequelize will add get/set/add/remove methods to the model instance.

```
// All categories associated to userId
User.findById(userId).getCategories()

// All categories create by userId
Category.findAll({
    where: {
        createdBy: userId
    }
})
```

Comment: This will give me all categories associated to a user. I will not be getting  `(categories associated to user) + (categories created by user)`.

Answer (score 0):

That should be

```
myUser = User();
myUser.categories();
```

Take a look to how defining and querying the n:m relations for
sequelize:
[n:m](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#nm)

Comment: This will give me all categories associated to a user. I will not be getting  `(categories associated to user) + (categories created by user)`.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
Category.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'CreateCategory'});

User.belongsToMany(models.Category, {through: 'CreateCategory','foreignKey':'createdBy' });
```

this will allow you to define an other relation with an other table that stores `createdBy` field of `Category` and `userId`

Comment: `hasMany` would only create a one-to-many relationship and not a many-to-many relationship. The `UserCategory` table is created in my case, but I do not know how to use the API to achieve what I'm doing instead of using a native query.

Comment: if you set 'hasMany' for both tables then you create many to many relation then you can use function that @jesusbv said correctly

Comment: The docs here http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#nm state `hasMany` as a more restrictive `belongsToMany` (which I've used; I DID NOT USE `belongsTo` - refer my question) And I'm aware of the fact I can get categories using user.categories. But it would give me categories associated to the user ONLY. I want a union of (categories associated to user)+(categories created by user) There seems to be no native way of achieving it in Sequelize.